# Customs for Yom Tov Sheini in Israel

Tags: minhag, tefilin, eretz-yisrael, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

My question concerns the observance of yom tov sheini for a person who is visiting Israel during a chag.

If the person is not observing yom tov sheini, are there any different customs they need to observe in Israel while it is yom tov sheini in the Diaspora? For example, on the second day of yom tov, would the man put on tefillin or should he daven without tefillin?

Comment: I'm confused. Either his custom is to treat it like a diasporan, like an Israeli, or as a Safek. Which are you asking about? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Now this is a dupe of the final question in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/325/